# Who is Nikumbila devi?

Tags: ramayana, devi, indrajit

Who is the devi Nikumbila worshipped by Indrajit through tantric rites. Is she [Maa Pratyangira](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pratyangira) or a local Lankan deity?

Answer (score 1):

In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=byXAMMlRrXQ&t=30s), Sri Siddesvarananda Bharati Swamy of Sri Siddeswari Pitham at Courtallam explained that the other name of Pratyangira is Nikhumbhila, who was worshipped by Indrajit.

[image]

***The video is in Telugu.***

---

He explains that sage AngIrasa first got the vision Devi in the form of Pratyangira and had composed mantras, which are embedded in Atharva Veda.

He had further explained that Pratyangira got the name of  Nikhumbhila, because once Pratyangira was worshipped by a demon by name Nikhumbha, using the mantras composed by Sage angIrasa and got the darshan of the former.